# How to add an active class to an anchor tag based on URL and Vanity URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, window.location

I have this working minus the part if the URL is www.mysite.com/home/.  It works if it is www.mysite.com/home/index.aspx, but not if you take off the index.aspx.  It also works for all other pages I have - page2.aspx, page3.aspx, etc...

Also, I might do a URL rewrite on the pages (so page2.aspx would be page2 and page3.aspx would be page3)

How do I adjust the below code to be able to add the class active to the active page.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
    .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $("nav a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});
```

HTML where the class is added:

```
 <nav class="clearfix">
  <a href="index.aspx">Home</a>
  <a href="page2.aspx">Page2</a>
  <a href="page3.aspx">Page3</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy Cow figured out how to do the no index!  I didn't think this was going to be so hard to get an answer on.  Still not sure on the vanity bit.  Might do separate post on that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Add active class to menu
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
    .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $("nav a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl)
            $(this).addClass("active");
        if (pgurl == '')
                $("nav a:first-child").addClass("active");
    })
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for `window.location.pathname`

```
$(function() {
    $("nav a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname || window.location.pathname == '')
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});
```

Comment: The / doesn't work.  So if it is www.mysite.com/home/ it does not add the active class to the <a href="index.aspx">Home</a>

Comment: @RooksStrife I've understood you wrong, check the edit

Comment: Same issue - does not work on the / - so if someone types in www.mysite.com/home/ the active class is not added to the <a href="index.aspx">Home</a> I am assuming bc the index page is not in the URL.  Even though the index page is being displayed (like a vanity URL).

Comment: @RooksStrife you assuming it right, the 'index.aspx' is hidden by the server, so you will need another check. See my edit

Comment: Ok, `window.location.pathname` is the thing that you need. Just play with it using `alert()` and handle the cases you need

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var s = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
if(!s)
    document.querySelector("nav > a:first-child").className = "active";
else
    document.querySelector("nav > a[href*='"+s+"']").className = "active";
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all.  Kill adding any active classes.  Unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I was wrong is distinct -1 not equal 1 now you can try again

Comment: Same issue as Vlad L - does not work on the / - so if someone types in www.mysite.com/home/ the active class is not added to the <a href="index.aspx">Home</a> I am assuming bc the index page is not in the URL. Even though the index page is being displayed (like a vanity URL).

Comment: Nope - same issue :]  Good gravy this is turning into quite the issue.

Comment: My mistake again, I forgot write the comparison :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the link with the same url part that you are looking for you can try this:

```
var lookup = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
$("a:regex(href, .*"+ lookup +".*)").addClass('active');
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Kill adding any active classes. Unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The code didn't work and stopped the active class from being added to any anchor tag when on the corresponding page.

Answer (score 0):

I know, maybe this is stupid solution, but:

```
  var current_url = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  $('.news #' + current_url).addClass('active');
```